# I found this file /vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php file is having some code. What is the explanation of below code?

Tags: module, customer, redirect, cookie, vendor

I want to know what actually these two lines of code are doing.

```
    $redirectUrl = $this->accountRedirect->getRedirectCookie();
    if (!$this->getScopeConfig()->getValue('customer/startup/redirect_dashboard') && $redirectUrl) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code above will Magento (after passing the conditions) to redirect the customer to the route saved in the redirect cookie after successful login if the configuration which says that all customers be redirected to their accounts' dashboard instead **Stores -> Configuration -> Customers -> Login Options -> Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in** is not enabled.

See class `vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/Account/Redirect.php` for more details on how the redirect route is used.